# OpenPose How to solve F0414 error of GPU memory?

Tags: python, openpose

Do anybody know what to do with this OpenPose error?

```
Starting OpenPose demo...
Configuring OpenPose...
Starting thread(s)...
Auto-detecting all available GPUs... Detected 1 GPU(s), using 1 of them starting at GPU 0.
F0414 17:01:38.075806  6648 syncedmem.cpp:71] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0)  out of memory
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

And there is nothing at the end. No error codes or something like that.
I'm using 1050Ti videocard, so I don't think that is the memory issue

Just for sure

```
Wed Apr 14 17:05:13 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 456.71       Driver Version: 456.71       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 105... WDDM  | 00000000:03:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 40%   30C    P8    N/A / 113W |    494MiB /  4096MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1000    C+G   ...bbwe\Microsoft.Photos.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1208    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1448    C+G   ...wekyb3d8bbwe\Video.UI.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2912    C+G   ...lPanel\SystemSettings.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3124    C+G   ...r\Application\browser.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7484    C+G   ...y\ShellExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7492    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe         N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9024    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\SearchApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9388    C+G   ...ekyb3d8bbwe\YourPhone.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9864    C+G   ...nputApp\TextInputHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10836    C+G   ...er_engine\wallpaper32.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13764    C+G   ...icrosoft VS Code\Code.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Downloaded last version of OpenPose from official GitHub server, cuDNN also installed